# Create a new column based on the maximum value in another column for a given sub index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe called `df`. It consists of Hour and Level as multiindex and Step1 as column. it looks as follows:

```
Step1
Types   
Hour    Level   
1   Level_0 4507.26700
Level_1 623.85960
Level_2 6240.49500
Level_4 23181.66600
Level_5 447.22240
... ... ...
8758    Level_W 59883.22444
Level_X 781.63500
Level_Y 4971.49200
Level_Z 4684.35940
Level_Z1    5994.00000
```

Step1 consists of values for each level for different hours. I want to create a new column called Step2 which has the maximum value among levels for each hour. I can get the maximum value for each hour using `df.groupby(["Hour"])["Step1"].max()` However, I also want to add this as a new column called Step2 in `df`.
Since the size of `df` and `df.groupby(["Hour"])["Step1"].max()` are not same, I was not able to do it.

What would be the appropriate way to create a new column called Step2 consisting of max value among different levels for the same hour? Also, I want to create another column called Step3 where the maximum value is present only in the same row as Level_0.

Comment: Please edit the dataset as its not clearly understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `transform`.

```
df['Step2'] = df.groupby(["Hour"])['Step1'].transform(np.max)
```

Comment: Please add quotes outside of Step1 as it is a column. Thank you!